# Decrypt and use PGP file

Tags: javascript, encryption, rsa, pgp

I am actually working on a Javascript solution to encrypt and decrypt messages using the same process as PGP (hybrid encryption -> AES + RSA).

I would like to know what is the method used by PGP to encrypt its files (public and private key) so I can support PGP in my Javascript application. I don't want a library that handles everything without being able to modify anything because I have some user whose key pair will have been generated by my application.

Thank you in advance for your answers and guidance.

Comment: This question is a bad fit for this site, being much too broad. [RFC 4880](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4880) describes all you need to know. Anyway: **do not write crypto code yourself** if there is any way to go with existing, tested code; [there are too many ways to break a lot](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4880#section-14). Have a look at [OpenPGP.JS](http://www.openpgpjs.org/), which will very likely support your use cases out of the box. If not, _very likely_ it is more reasonable to stick with standards and modify your requirements.

Comment: Alright, thank you for this answer, I did not mean not to stick to libraries, I meant being able to get the key pair after the decryption process in order to use them with my existing solution

Comment: The JavaScript library linked above offers full key handling, including generation, importing and exporting keys.

Comment: "I would like to know what is the method used by PGP to encrypt its files (public and private key) so I can support PGP in my Javascript application." Sorry, but that question screams *please read the specification* whichever way you turn it.